# How to set hosted domain parameter in Google OAuth2 AccountChooser with Java config?

Tags: java, spring-security-oauth2, google-oauth

Currently I have working OAuth2 authentication flow with following Java config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
@Import(SecurityWebAppInitializer.class)
public class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration {

    @Resource
    private GoogleClientSecrets googleClientSecrets;

    @Resource
    private AccessTokenRequest accessTokenRequest;

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails googleResource() {
        AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails details = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
        GoogleClientSecrets.Details web = googleClientSecrets.getWeb();
        details.setId((String) web.get("project_id"));
        details.setClientId(web.getClientId());
        details.setClientSecret(web.getClientSecret());
        details.setAccessTokenUri(web.getTokenUri());
        details.setUserAuthorizationUri(web.getAuthUri());
        details.setTokenName((String) web.get("token_name"));

        String commaSeparatedScopes = (String) web.get("scope");
        details.setScope(parseScopes(commaSeparatedScopes));
        details.setPreEstablishedRedirectUri(web.getRedirectUris().get(0));
        details.setUseCurrentUri(false);
        details.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.query);
        details.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form);
        return details;
    }

    private List<String> parseScopes(String commaSeparatedScopes) {
        List<String> scopes = newArrayList();
        Collections.addAll(scopes, commaSeparatedScopes.split(","));
        return scopes;
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter oAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter(
            OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate, ResourceServerTokenServices resourceServerTokenServices) {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter =
                new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter("/googleLogin");
        filter.setRestTemplate(oAuth2RestTemplate);
        filter.setTokenServices(resourceServerTokenServices);
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserAuthenticationConverter userTokenConverter() {
        return new DefaultUserAuthenticationConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter(UserAuthenticationConverter userTokenConverter) {
        GoogleAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter = new GoogleAccessTokenConverter();
        accessTokenConverter.setUserTokenConverter(userTokenConverter);
        return new GoogleAccessTokenConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public GoogleTokenServices tokenServices(AccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter) {
        GoogleTokenServices tokenServices = new GoogleTokenServices();
        GoogleClientSecrets.Details web = googleClientSecrets.getWeb();
        tokenServices.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo");
        tokenServices.setClientId(web.getClientId());
        tokenServices.setClientSecret(web.getClientSecret());
        tokenServices.setAccessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter);
        return tokenServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestTemplate googleRestTemplate() {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(googleResource(), new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(accessTokenRequest));
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2ClientContextFilter oauth2ClientContextFilter() {
        return new OAuth2ClientContextFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint clientAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        return new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/googleLogin");
    }
}
```

and `client_secret.json` for my google service:

```
{
  "web": {
    "client_id": "...",
    "project_id": "...",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "...",
    "redirect_uris": [
      "http://localhost:8888/googleLogin",
      "http://localhost:8888/googleLogin/"
    ],
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
    "token_name": "authorization_code"
  }
}
```

The problem is I don't know where to set [hosted domain](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#hd-param) parameter in java code. I was trying to find solution over the stackoverflow, but only saw solutions with JS or PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I found out `AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider#getRedirectForAuthorization` is responsible for constructing redirect URI but available parameters there are limited so the only choice is to add HD parameter to `auth_uri` in `client_secrets.json`:

```
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?hd=<domain>",
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the hd parameter to the URL worked.  Adding **?hd=MYDOMAIN.com** to the **security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri** property did the trick.

This basic config works for me in application.properties - you can do that or yaml.  When the login request goes to show the google login, the domain pre-populates on the form.

If you have logged in before under a private domain hosted by google and a gmail account and previously needed to pick the correct account, this will automatically choose your account with the matching domain and send you through to the secured resource.

```
security.oauth2.client.client-id=123456789-abc123456789.apps.googleusercontent.com
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri=https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?hd=MYDOMAIN.com
security.oauth2.client.authentication-scheme=query
security.oauth2.client.scope=email
security.oauth2.client.
security.oauth2.client.client-authentication-scheme=form
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
security.oauth2.resource.prefer-token-info=false
```